# Pass data to tableView cell swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a Table with a cell in it. Within the Cell there is a Picker View

[image]

Now I want to pass data (an array of objects) from the Parent Controller to the Table View Cell so I can show the data in the Picker View

```
var foodServings:[FoodUnit]=[]
func tableView(tableView:UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:NSIndexPath)->UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("recipeIngredientCell",forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ReceiptIngredientsViewCell
    let row = indexPath.row
    cell.ingredientName.text = foods[row].name
    cell.ingredientText.text = foodQuantities[row]

  // cell.foodServings = self.foodServings

    return cell

}
```

I hoped I can send Data to the Cell but this didnt work.

I try to clearify it a bit:

[Thats how the table is constructed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GvLKw.jpg)

with:

```
 cell.ingredientName.text = foods[row].name
 cell.ingredientText.text = foodQuantities[row]
```

I can access the cell Labels for example bean and the text in the textview

But to populate the picker view i need to send an array of data to each cell so that i can populate the picker view.

Comment: Actually you can and the way you used is correct. What's your problem?

Comment: have u done this , if yes then how you pass the data to tableview cell

Answer (score 1):

If you are just passing the data you may use global variables/constructor for passing the value to the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Please check these:

- is the cell with "recipeIngredientCell" identifier is there in your storyboard?
- is `foods` array is filled with your data?
- is `foodQuantities` array is filled with your data?
- have you implemented tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:) method? This method must return number of your rows, for example `foods.count`

Comment: Yes all has been checked the problem is to pass an array of objects to the cell which can then populate the picker view

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can check out [this](http://codewithchris.com/uipickerview-example/) tutorial about `UIPickerView`

Did you connect the `UIPickerViewDelegate` and `UIPickerViewDataSource` to your viewController?

After that, make sure you have implemented those delegate methods:

```
 // The number of rows of data
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return foodServings.count
}

 // The data to return for the row and component (column) that's being passed in
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return foodServings[row]
}

// Catpure the picker view selection
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    // This method is triggered whenever the user makes a change to the picker selection.
    // You can update your cell's UI here. For example:
    let indexpath = NSIndexPath(row: , section:)
    let cell = self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)      
    cell.yourTextField.text = foodServings[row]
}
```

From what you have provided us, I can only tell that your `foodServings` array is empty, so could you please show me all the codes in this class?

Comment: perhaps i was a bit imprecise. the picker view works but i need to pass an array with objects from a viewcontroller to the cell controller which i can later on use to populate the picker view

Comment: @chrissychristancuvic Then please be precise enough and edit your question, try to put more codes, explain what you have right now, what you want to do, and what's your problem, instead of putting one block of code and let people guess your intend.